# Play! framework link

Tags: java, web, playframework-2.0, web-development-server

I got a List of **Forums** and I want to create a link for each one:

```
<ul>
@for(forum <- forums) {
<li>
    <a href="@{Forums.show(forum.getId)}">@forum.getName()</a>
</li>
}
```

this it the result for the  tag:

```
<a href="SimpleResult(200, Map(Content-Type -&gt; text/html; charset=utf-8))">bla bla</a>
```

I thought it will produce a link, like in this tutorial:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/firstapp

what change is need to be done?

Comment: Your question is tagged [tag:playframework-2.0] but you've linked to the v1.0 docs. Start by looking at [the right documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/Home).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. found the solution - it should be done like this:

```
<a href="@routes.Forums.show(forum.getId())">@forum.getName()</a>
```